# Filtering with map in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, babeljs

I'm trying to do a filter in my app, where the content of the table to filter is defined in the reducer and comes as a state to the component. To do this i'm adding a filter to the mapping of the array.

```
{tilesData
    .map((tile, i) => (
        <GridListTile key={i}>
            <img src={projectA} style={style.img} alt={tile.title} />
            <GridListTileBar
              title={<span>{tile.title}</span>}
              subtitle={<span>{tile.address}, {tile.state} </span>}
              actionIcon={
                <Link to = 'project'>
                  <IconButton onClick={goToProject(i)} color='contrast'>
                    <VisibilityIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Link>

              }
            />
          </GridListTile>
      ))
      .filter(tilesData.title === project)
}
```

After doing this, it throws the following error:

> TypeError: false is not a function

Comment: Do - `tilesData.filter((tile) => tile.title === project).map((tile, i) => (`. Filter needs a callback function, not a Boolean. It's also better to filter out items that you don't won't before transforming them to something else. That's why filter should be before map.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself.